# Clojure: Reducing large lazy collection eats up memory

Tags: performance, memory, clojure, sequence, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to Clojure. I have the following code, which creates an infinite lazy sequence of numbers:

```
(defn generator [seed factor]
  (drop 1 (reductions 
            (fn [acc _] (mod (* acc factor) 2147483647))
            seed 
            ; using dummy infinite seq to keep the reductions going
            (repeat 1))))
```

Each number in the sequence is dependent on the previous calculation. I'm using `reductions` because I need all the intermediate results.

I then instantiate two generators like so:

```
(def gen-a (generator 59 16807))
(def gen-b (generator 393 48271))
```

I then want to compare `n` consecutive results of these sequences, for large n, and return the number of times they are equal.

At first I did something like:

```
(defn run []
  (->> (interleave gen-a gen-b)
       (partition 2)
       (take 40000000)
       (filter #(apply = %))
       (count)))
```

It was taking far too long and I saw the program's memory usage spike to about 4GB. With some `println`s I saw that after about 10 million iterations it got really slow, so I was thinking that maybe `count` needed to store the entire sequence in memory, so I changed it to use `reduce`:

```
(defn run-2 []
  (reduce
    (fn [acc [a b]]
      (if (= a b)
        (inc acc)
        acc))
    0
    (take 40000000 (partition 2 (interleave gen-a gen-b)))))
```

Still, it was allocating a lot of memory and slowing down significantly after the first couple of millions. I'm pretty sure that it's storing the entire lazy sequence in memory but I'm not sure why, so I tried to manually throw away the head:

```
(defn run-3 []
  (loop [xs (take 40000000 (partition 2 (interleave gen-a gen-b)))
         total 0]
    (cond
      (empty? xs) total
      (apply = (first xs)) (recur (rest xs) (inc total))
      :else (recur (rest xs) total))))
```

Again, same results. This stumped me because I'm reading that all of the functions I'm using to create my `xs` sequence are lazy, and since I'm only using the current item I'm expecting it to use constant memory.

Coming from a Python background I'm basically trying to emulate [Python Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). I'm probably missing something obvious, so I'd really appreciate some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generators are not (lazy) sequences.

You are holding on to the head here:

```
(def gen-a (generator 59 16807))
(def gen-b (generator 393 48271))
```

`gen-a` and `gen-b` are gobal vars referring to the head a sequence.

You probably want something like:

```
(defn run []
  (->> (interleave (generator 59 16807) (generator 393 48271))
       (partition 2)
       (take 40000000)
       (filter #(apply = %))
       (count)))
```

Alternatively, define `gen-a` and `gen-b` as functions:

```
(defn gen-a
  []
  (generator 59 16807)))
...

(defn run []
  (->> (interleave (gen-a) (gen-b))
       (partition 2)
       (take 40000000)
       (filter #(apply = %))
       (count)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought that `generator` returned a lazy sequence of items 2 -> infinity. Edit: nevermind, I wasn't aware that `def` was holding the head of the sequence.

Comment: @orangeblock it does, the problem is that you referred to the head of the lazy list from a global (uncollectable) var. edit: yes, that's what I mean :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can get Python-style generator functions in Clojure [using the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python). Just use `lazy-gen` and `yield` like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]  ))

(defn rand-gen
  [seed factor]
  (t/lazy-gen
    (loop [acc seed]
      (let [next (mod (* acc factor) 2147483647)]
        (t/yield next)
        (recur next)))))

(defn run2 [num-rand]
  (->> (interleave
         ; restrict to [0..99] to simulate bad rand #'s
         (map #(mod % 100) (rand-gen 59 16807))
         (map #(mod % 100) (rand-gen 393 48271)))
       (partition 2)
       (take num-rand)
       (filter #(apply = %))
       (count)))

(t/spyx (time (run2 1e5))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e3
(t/spyx (time (run2 1e6))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e4
(t/spyx (time (run2 1e7))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e5
```

with result:

```
"Elapsed time:   409.697922 msecs"   (time (run2 100000.0))   =>   1025
"Elapsed time:  3250.592798 msecs"   (time (run2 1000000.0))  =>   9970
"Elapsed time: 32995.194574 msecs"   (time (run2 1.0E7))      => 100068
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using `reductions`, you could build a lazy sequence directly.  This answer uses `lazy-cons` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#simplified-lazy-sequence-generation) (you could also [use `lazy-seq` from clojure.core](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq)).

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]  ))

(defn rand-gen
  [seed factor]
  (let [next (mod (* seed factor) 2147483647)]
    (t/lazy-cons next (rand-gen next factor))))

(defn run2 [num-rand]
  (->> (interleave
         ; restrict to [0..99] to simulate bad rand #'s
         (map #(mod % 100) (rand-gen 59 16807))
         (map #(mod % 100) (rand-gen 393 48271)))
       (partition 2)
       (take num-rand)
       (filter #(apply = %))
       (count)))

(t/spyx (time (run2 1e5))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e3
(t/spyx (time (run2 1e6))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e4
(t/spyx (time (run2 1e7))) ; expect ~1% will overlap => 1e5
```

with results:

```
"Elapsed time:   90.42 msecs"  (time (run2   100000.0)) =>   1025 
"Elapsed time:  862.60 msecs"  (time (run2  1000000.0)) =>   9970
"Elapsed time: 8474.25 msecs"  (time (run2      1.0E7)) => 100068
```

Note that the execution times are about 4x faster, since we have cut out the generator function stuff that we weren't really using anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning Clojure and I've seen lazy-seq a few times but haven't got around to using it yet. Will definitely check it out next time. Also, I don't really want to use third party libraries at this stage, plus the question was really more about the memory issue.